# sendgrid webhook connections open from tool

Tags: email, sendgrid

From mail settings page, I configured webhook url and tested integration. Its gave me 504 error.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Exception (504) Reason: \"channel/connection is not open\""}]}
```

But still I saved and sent email . webhook hit the configured url. but It doesn't have any data in POST. I guess there is some problem in sendgrid server. When It will be back?

Comment: Did you resolved this?